# Clipping / Masking element with SVG

Tags: css, svg, mask

I have the following:

A `.circle` with an `.object` inside of it. See the code below (and see the full screen example).

I want the `.object` to be coming from the bottom (animated), so the circle could be `overflow: hidden;`, but I want the `.object` to be out from the top. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuDvR.jpg) for final result.

**In short:** the `.object` should only be the same as `.circle` at its bottom.

So I thought that a `svg` mask (which is a square with a border radius of 50% at the bottom) could do the trick. So far no luck to get that working.

Did I miss something? Am I not using it correctly? Can't SVG's be used to masks `div` elements? Or is there another *obvious* solution to this problem?

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  background: gold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  background: LightCoral;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: url(#clipping);
}
.object {
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="circle">
    <div class="object"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipping">
          <path class="cls-1" d="M0,0H300V150H0V0ZM300,150A150,150,0,0,1,0,150" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish - can you clarify?

Comment: You can have masks in SVG, will be posting code shortly.

Comment: @MichaelMullany I added an image of the final result I want to achieve, does that clarify it enough?

Comment: Do your circle and blue object need to be HTML elements?  This would be very easy if all elements were SVG elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use SVG clips or masks for this.  Just wrap your object in a div that has a round bottom and overflow set to hidden.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  background: gold;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  background: LightCoral;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.mask {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.object {
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="mask">
      <div class="object"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that was the obvious answer I couldn't come up with. Thanks.